# How to get and use SECRET VARIABLES from Azure DevOps release pipeline, in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline. Within that pipeline, I have a .NET 6 integration test stage, which uses the C# code:

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySetting");`

to get and retrieve different settings at runtime, for running the tests against different environments/users/etc. I set these settings in the "Variable Groups" section of the release pipeline, and my code consumes them, and everything works great.

Here's what my variable group looks like in DevOps:

So for instance, during a test run, my code calls:

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServiceAdminApiKey");`

and it pulls the variable straight from the variable group, and works nicely.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Now I need to change some of these sensitive variables into being ***SECRETS***. So I update them as secrets in the variable group:

And, [according to the documentation][3],:

> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into environment variables for scripts. You need to explicitly map secret variables.

Cool, makes sense. So now, in a powershell script task, I'm trying to map them explicitly, and then set them as environment variables to be consumed by my C# code, like so:

And here, I attempt to manually map them as environment variables to be used by my script:

However, it's not working. After this powershell script runs, and my tests begin, whenever the C# code calls:

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySecret");`

for any of these secrets, it just returns null/empty. I have been scouring the internet, and it seems like what I am doing *should* be working.... I have also tried many different variations of syntax, i've tried using `$(MySecret)` instead of `$env:MySecret`, and many others, but none of it seems to work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is some combination of two things:

1. You're using the same name for the secret and non-secret version
2. You're setting a variable using a `vso` command. That creates a *pipeline* variable. If I recall correctly, pipeline variables are mapped as environment variables at the *start* of the job running, so if you create a new variable at runtime, it won't be mapped as an environment variable.

#2 is definitely an issue, and #1 *may* be part of the issue.

Basically, if you want to create an environment variable from a pipeline secret in PowerShell, use  `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FooSecret', $env:Foo)`.

And from a philosophical perspective, I strongly advise *against* using pipeline variables for application configuration; this is tightly coupling your application to Azure Pipelines. Typically, you'd use a secret storage mechanism such as Azure KeyVault and integrate your application with it so that secret values can automatically be retrieved at runtime without having to rely on environment variables being set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, #2 sounds like a potential issue for sure so I will investigate that avenue and report back. I was unaware how the vso command interacts with the job timing, this is great information. For #1, this is simply the latest iteration of naming conventions I'd been using, so I don't think that's the issue, I have tried many different combinations of names/references heh, just because I didn't know what else to try.

Comment: Hmm. It still seems like it's not working.... I have a Write-Host command printing the secrets, and they display as ***, so it's clearly pulling the correct secret values... but it just doesn't seem to be setting them?? Here's an example of my script command currently:

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('SearchServiceAdminApiKey', $env:SearchServiceAdminApiKey)

any other ideas? Thanks again for the initial thoughts...

Comment: I have also tried using this SetEnvironmentVariable command to overwrite a NON secret variable, and it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm still misunderstanding how the flow of all of this works..